# How to write to a file in parallel using OpenMp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have the following code which works perfectly in Serial:

```
while(fread(in, sizeof(in), 1, fp_input) && ++count){              
      Encode();
      fseek(fp_out, (count-1)*sizeof(out), SEEK_SET);
      fwrite(out, sizeof(out), 1, fp_out);
      time_spent = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
}
```

To parallelize the code , I use the following OpenMP directives:

```
#pragma omp parallel private(in, out)
   {   
      while(read(fd_read, in, sizeof(in)) && ++count){ 
         Encode(); //take input from in and writes to out
         fseek(fp_out, (count-1)*sizeof(out), SEEK_SET);
         fwrite(out, sizeof(out), 1, fp_out);
         time_spent = (double)(stop - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;   
      }   
   }
```

It is imperative that I maintain order as write into output file so that it may be decrypted later. But I am not able to achieve it, how do structure the OpenMp directives to achieve order in the file write?

**Updated the code** to the following and earned significant speedup over the serial code:

```
while(fread(chunk_input, sizeof(chunk_input), 1, fp_input) == 1){ 
      int block_no = 0;
      #pragma omp parallel for private(block_no)
      for(block_no=0; block_no<CHUNK_SIZE; block_no += 16){
         unsigned char in[16], out[16];
         memcpy(in, &chunk_input[block_no], 16);          
         Encode(in, out);
         memcpy(&chunk_output[block_no], out, 16);
      }          
      fwrite(chunk_output, sizeof(chunk_output), 1, fp_out);
   }
```

Comment: read into a buffer in serial, encode in parallel, write buffer in serial

Comment: But the encode function is not parallelizable

Comment: Then what exactly are you trying to speed up? Reading and writing data from a file with multiple concurrent threads is going to have non-deterministic results. Sometimes thread 0 will write first, sometimes thread 1, sometimes, they'll be intermingled. The only way to make it deterministic is to serialize it. That means the only thing left to parallelize is the encoding. If you don't think that's parallelizable, then there's nothing left to do.

Comment: Is there any way to use offsets to seek to different sections of the file? Since the size of the input and output buffers are of constant size, is there a way to allow threads to write in parallel into the file?

Comment: Even if you could do this, I doubt it would go any faster. You should first determine if single file IO bandwidth is limited by CPU performance. If not, threading won't help.

Comment: Fix your `encode` function: make it as pure as possible - it should take `in` as an argument and return `out`, and no global state (ever!). Then it should be usable in parallel. I/O in parallel will almost never work because there is only one access channel to the I/O device: trying to use that in parallel will just cause conflicts behind the scenes when the I/O controller will try to service requests to different parts of the file. So it will not be faster and probably will be slower.